# Creating two types of users Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, rails-models

I'm creating a rails app that has two types of users: drivers and mechanics.

So far I have the drivers class (called "users") completely set up with profiles and attributes with a "cars" model connected so they can add cars to their profile.

Now I need to create "mechanic" users that will be like a business page, with address, services offered, etc, and these mechanics will then add drivers as their customers.

My intuition was to create a new mechanic model and set it up the same way as I did the user model but with the appropriate schema. I think I may run into issues with the `sessions helper` though, because "user" is used in a lot of the functions.  I could duplicate these items in the sessions helper and replace "user" with "mechanic", but I'm not sure if that would work or not.

I considered using a gem like cancancan for user restrictions but it seems questionable. Also wondering if I could use the current "User" class and create two more models (drivers and mechanics) that inherit from User with specific functions for each.

I really need an idea of which direction to start in to make this happen, so any advice, links to helpful rails casts, etc would be amazing.  Thanks!

**sessions helper**

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

  # Redirects to stored location (or to the default).
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(root_url)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
  end

  # Stores the URL trying to be accessed.
  def store_location
    session[:forwarding_url] = request.url if request.get?
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :phone, presence:true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  def feed
    Car.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end
end
        cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
      end

      def current_user?(user)
        user == current_user
      end

      # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
      def current_user
        if (user_id = session[:user_id])
          @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
        elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
          user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
          if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
            log_in user
            @current_user = user
          end
        end
      end

      # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
      def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
      end

      def forget(user)
        user.forget
        cookies.delete(:user_id)
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
      end

      # Logs out the current user.
      def log_out
        forget(current_user)
        session.delete(:user_id)
        @current_user = nil
      end

      # Redirects to stored location (or to the default).
      def redirect_back_or(default)
        redirect_to(root_url)
        session.delete(:forwarding_url)
      end

      # Stores the URL trying to be accessed.
      def store_location
        session[:forwarding_url] = request.url if request.get?
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend thinking about your setup slightly differently by separating authentication from authorization. User, Driver and Mechanic are separate but related concepts. A user is anyone who can access your application mechanics and drivers are roles assigned to a user (what they are authorized to do).

There are a variety of different ways to approach this and not knowing the exact nature of your application it would be hard to suggest a particular solution, but I think if you untangle these concerns you'll be much better off in the long run.

Here is a link to a good resource to get you started:

http://railsapps.github.io/rails-authorization.html

Answer (score 0):

Use cancan gem .. you can find an episode of it in railscasts.com

Comment: cancan isn't supported by rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

I think, `devise` gem should help.

Check the getting started section (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/README.md#getting-started), where you can find information how to create different types of users.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check out Pundit gem: https://github.com/elabs/pundit I used it on a recent project and liked it.